# clang++: howto improve warning from stack-address-return

Tags: clang, warnings, clang++

for the following functions:

```
const char *fstack() 
{
char tab[100];

return tab;
}

const char *fc_str()
{
std::string s{"some text"};

return s.c_str();
}

const char * f_stringstream()
{
std::ostringstream s;

s<<"another text";

return s.str().c_str();
}
```

clang issues the warning [-Wreturn-stack-address], though the later 2 are not exactly on the stack but rather already deleted and on the heap. Anyway.

What must I change in the following code or call of clang++ to get the same warning:

```
class C1 {
public:
std::string str;
};

const char* fun_class() 
{
C1 c;
c.str="class text";

return c.str.c_str();
}
```

because in the last case I get no warning at all.

I read the list of all available clang++ warning to find something suitable, greped for stack and heap, but nothing worked out.